# How to pass variable from html view to angular controller to access by scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS
I have a variable that consists of objects

```
var listitems=Model.objectname;
```

how can I pass (listitems) - controller to useby $scope

I tried to use it on ng-init and access on the controller from $scope

```
<div ng-app="angularApp" ng-controller="angularController"
    ng-init="values=@listitems)">
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Answer (score 1):

Everything you put in the `$scope` can be used inside any html attributes that start with `ng-` or by using `{{ }}` brackets.

So for this example,

```
$scope.listitems = Model.objectname;
```

Then you can use it in your HTML by `{{ listitems }}` anywhere, or if its in `ng-init` you want to use it, do something like:

```
ng-init="getValues(listitems)"
```

when getValues is your function

Answer (score 0):

Out side variables does not accept in scope, if you want to add variable to `$scope` object from outside, you can take reference of the `$scope` object like

`var scopeItem = angular.element(document.getElementById('controller_id')).scope(); 
scopeItem.values = Model.objectname;`